# Fetching and Opening Folders in a New Tab using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

If I have a folder that is hosted somewhere (like google drive or GitHub) can I fetch those files with JavaScript and open them in a new tab? I have made something like this before but for single files hosted on GitHub:

```
var newWin = open();
fetch({URL of raw file on GitHub repository})
.then(data=>{data.text()
.then(text=>{newWin.document.write(text);})});
```

This code has worked perfectly for me, but it is unable to open webpages that are made up of multiple files (most webpages). Is it possible to use vanilla JavaScript to open a folder similar to my example? I am ok with switching where the folder is hosted but I really want to use vanilla JavaScript. I also do not want to use GitHub pages or any other website hosting platform.

I have spent a lot of time trying to get something like this to work, but I have had limited success. Here is a list of the solutions I have tried:

**1. Condensing web projects into a single html file**
With web projects that are relatively simple, I am able to move the files manually into a html file using the  and  tag. This begins to fall apart when I get to folders that have a lot of files with varied file types like images. I have tried using Chrome extensions like single file to condense websites but it is not able to consistently condense webpages. I also have first host the file on my computer to get it to work.

**2. Looping through a GitHub repository**
I have tried to loop through the condense of GitHub repositories, use the fetch() function and add them to the new window by appending them to the head. This seemed promising but I ended up not being able to get this work from lack of knowledge.

**3. Using Google Drive**
I have tried to upload my folder to google drive and getting the folder from there. I remember being able to get the files but not knowing what to do with the returned object again because of lack of knowledge.

Any help would be so amazing! I have been trying to do something like this for a long time and it has became a problem out of my skill level. I am a mostly self taught programmer so my knowledge is very spotty.